# ListBox won't remove the first item in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //ADD
{
    listBox.Items.Add("some");
    listBox.Items.Add("text");         

}


private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //DELETE
{

    if (!(listBox.SelectedIndex == -1))
       listBox.Items.Remove(listBox.SelectedItem);
    else
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("You have not selected an item");

}
```

The `ListBox` won't delete the first item sometimes. The reason is that after I delete an item a white border appears on the previous item. I don't know why this border appears. See Image to see what I mean. When the white border appears and I try to delete the first item, it says that I have not selected an item. **If I save 3 times the same item and delete the second, the bug appears.**

Try it out. for example some, some,some

[image]

Comment: Can't reprocude what you mean, correct behaviour, see here: http://imgur.com/a/0Brvt

Comment: @DoubleVoid try  listBox.Items.Add("some"),listBox.Items.Add("some"),listBox.Items.Add("some"); and delete at first the second some

Comment: It now behaves like this: http://imgur.com/yNyPJFU ... seems okay to me

Comment: @DoubleVoid Add 3 Times the same item not one time. Per button click one item.

Comment: Just bind it to an ObservableCollection and add/remove on the collection. Don't waste your time playing game like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the item from its position rather than the item itself. I found doing it no longer selects another item as the focus is completely removed from the listbox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (listBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
      listBox.Items.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);

   else
      System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("You have not selected an item");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in `button1_click` event should be something like this

```
var index = listBox.SelectedIndex;

if (index != -1)
{
    // remove item
    listBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);

    // select a new item
    if (listBox.Items.Count > index)
        listBox.SelectedIndex = index;
    else
        listBox.SelectedIndex = index - 1;
 }
 else
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("You have not selected an item");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the next item like this:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1))
        {
            int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);

            if (index > 0)
                listBox1.SetSelected(index - 1,true);
            else if(listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                listBox1.SetSelected(0, true);


        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("You have not selected an item");
    }
```

behaviour:[image: Behaviour]

Comment: This will not remove the correct item in the listbox